# the non-abelian subgroups of the Lamplighter group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group, direct-sum, wreath-product

The lamplighter group can be defined by the semidirect product:
$$
L_2=(\mathbb{Z} _2) \wr \mathbb{Z} \cong \bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{2}  \rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z},$$

where $\phi(1)$ "shifts" every element in $\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{2} $ to the right by $1$.

I am trying to classify all the non-abelian subgroups of the Lamplighter group. I know the obvious non-abelian subgroups of the form: $K \rtimes_\phi H$, where $K$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{2}$   and $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. I was wondering if all the non-abelian subgroups are of this form.

Any idea or reference would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about the abelianization of the group? If so, say so. If not, why did you write "I tried to compute the abelianization of the group"?

Comment: Sorry I put that there by mistake

Comment: There are subgroups of the form $K \rtimes_\phi H$ in which $H$ is a subgroup of a conjugate of the specified complement ${\mathbb Z}$, rather than being a subgroup of that complement itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help!